# merging and unmerging uiimages

Tags: xcode, uiimage, nsmutablearray, nsdata

I would like to know the best way to merge (for lack of a better word) many UIImages together, so that I can send them in an email or upload them to Dropbox as one file, and then be able to  un-merge them at a later date from a different iDevice.

Currently I am saving the images to an NSMutableDictionary with the image data as the object and the filename as the key. I then use an NSKeyedArchiver to create an NSData object out of my NSMutableDictionary. I attached this data to an email, and send it off, for import on another device. There I can NSKeyedUnarchiver my NSMutableDictionary and I have all may images and their respective filenames readily available. This works great if I only have 5 to 10 images, but when I get into the 50 - 100 images there is obliviously memory problems as the NSMutableDictionary gets to large. Below is the code I'm using right now

```
NSData *imageToAddToEmail;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToSend = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *filePathBrokenUp;


for (int i = 0; i < [arrayForPhotoURLs count]; i++)
{
    imageToAddToEmail = UIImagePNGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[arrayForPhotoURLs objectAtIndex:i]]]);
    filePathBrokenUp = [[arrayForPhotoURLs objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    if (imageToAddToEmail != nil) [dictionaryToSend setObject:imageToAddToEmail forKey:[filePathBrokenUp lastObject]];
}


NSData *dataToSend = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionaryToSend];
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to go about merging 50-100 UIImages together, keeping in mind that they later need to be un-merged? Thanks.